Ideal timeframe to consider for elasticity curve
I have transaction data for luxury retail domain. It is roughly 5 years of transaction data which provides week / month level details in terms of number of units being sold at a given price point. I want to use this data to create elasticity curve. The elasticity curves are needed at a product level so that we can estimate potential units sold for any given price point.
However, I am not sure what is the ideal duration of the data which I should consider for this? Should I consider entire history or just most recent data? Could you please share point of view on how much data is sufficient and why?

There does not exist an ideal time frame, it depends on the nature of the data on your prediction horizon - long run or short run predictions - as well as other matters such as data availability. However, I think it could be argued that the more data the better so at least you need a positive reason to exclude any data.

Thank you @JesperHybel. Based on a few other paper, we are attempting this with 2 years of data for now. We will increase the timeframe based on the results.

One of the dangers of using short time series such as 2 years is that you underestimate the probability of large shocks. Example: The recent energy crisis and electricity prices. This may or may not be a relevant consideration, depending on the nature of your project.
